# Boolean Logic (Order of operations) A and B or C

Tags: search, boolean, logic

I am creating a "Basic Search" bar that users can type in terms.
I am unsure of the order of operations for boolean logic.

If someone types terms(With no quotes):

**A and B or C**

What is the correct way to treat this?

**(A and B) or (C)**

OR

**(A) and (B or C)**

Comment: I think this belongs in ux.stackexchange.com, but FWIW in standard Boolean logic the precedence rules make NOT highest, then AND, then OR.

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller Why? There's no mention of Unix,etc. in the question..?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The `ux` in ux.stackexchange.com is for "user experience," not Unix.  My point is that there are implicit issues here about how to present Boolean search options--is the application such that the end users are expected to understand Boolean logic (e.g. in a programming context), or will they possibly be barely computer-literate (e.g. in a library card catalog search), or somewhere in between?  If the OP is "unsure of the order of operations" then how confident is he that his users are not equally unsure?

Comment: @dodgethesteamroller Heh.  My bad, sorry.

Comment: Lawyers are the target users.  Most have no idea, some have training in searching technique...which is why I want to be sure of the order.

Comment: @Max87: When lawyers are involved, assume nothing.  ;)  Seriously, use the established precedence rules, but put them right there on the screen.  Assuming non-programmers understand Boolean logic is a major UI fail.

Comment: I just tried ((A) && (B) || (C)) in JS the result was same as in ((A && B) || (C)) then I tried it with ((A) || (B) && (C)) and this resulted as if it was ((A) || (B && C)). So I presume that there is an order similar to multiplication then adding with AND preceding OR

Answer (score 14):

Wikipedia to the rescue, this should help:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

From the looks of things, it would appear that `AND` takes precedence over `OR` in most languages.

Answer (score 12):

Based on Quetzalcoatl's response, the correct answer for the OP question is:

(A and B) or C

That's the equivalent for "A and B or C"

Although Quetzalcoatl's link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) speaks about programming languages (as this site does), a more common precedence is specified for general logic in wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence

Answer (score -4):

(A) and (B or C)

and means intersection or "like" union

Like in math

"AND" is like a multiplier and "OR" like a sum

in a "truth table"

OR
A     | B     | result
true  | true  | true
true  | false | true
true  | false | true
false | false | false

AND
A | B     | result
true  | true  | true
true  | false | false
true  | false | false
false | false | false

Comment: The OP is not asking about the meanings of AND and OR, but their relative precedence.